# jQuery plugin for displaying tooltips with customizable events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for some jquery plugin for showing tooltip boxes. 
Main feature that I'm looking for is customizeable event handlers, saying when tooltip should be displayed/hide.

For example, I would like to show tooltip for some div

```
$('#div').tooltip({
   text      : 'Hello, I\'m div',
   showEvent : 'mouseenter',
   hideEvent : 'mouseleave'
});
```

..or I would like to show tooltip for some input

```
$('#input').tooltip({
   text      : 'Hello, I\'m div',
   showEvent : 'focus',
   hideEvent : 'blur'
});
```

Comment: You can make tooltips with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this awesome plugin: [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: I've also found some nice lightweight plugin http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/